# How to send notifications to Laravel Users with Onesignal notification channel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, onesignal

I'm trying to use laravel-notification-channels/onesignal with Laravel 9, Inertia React project.
For first I setup the client in this way:

```
    useEffect(() => {
            OneSignal.init({
                appId: "PRIVATE-KEY"
            });
    }, []);
```

Testing from Onesignal panel the client is listening.
For the back-end I have created a Notification:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\OneSignalChannel;
use NotificationChannels\OneSignal\OneSignalMessage;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\BroadcastMessage;
use App\Models\Order;


class OrderPlacedNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $order;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order = $order;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database', 'broadcast', OneSignalChannel::class];
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'order' => $this->order,
        ];
    }

    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'order' => $this->order
        ]);
    }

    public function toOneSignal($notifiable)
    {
        return OneSignalMessage::create()
            ->setSubject("Nuovo ordine!")
            ->setBody("Vedi l'ordine.")
            ->setUrl('http://onesignal.com');
    }

}
```

and I send the notification via controller to all users.
All config setted but I can't listen to the user.

Comment: Are you sure users are subscribed to push notifications?

Comment: I found the solution, In my client at the init function I sent that the user subscribe to the specfic interest, and in backend I send notifications to the specific segment

Comment: what package are you using?

Comment: @RoseRiyadh Laravel notifications channels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I found the solution. In my client I subscibe user to the specific interest and in backend I send notifictions at the users with that specific interest:

Frontend

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(auth.user) {

            window.Echo.private(`App.Models.User.${auth.user.id}`).notification(notification => {
                console.log(notification);
                setNotifications(() => [...notifications, notification]);
            })
            OneSignal.init(
                {
                    appId: "KEY",
                },
                //Automatically subscribe to the new_app_version tag
                OneSignal.sendTag("orders", "orders", tagsSent => {
                // Callback called when tag has finished sending
                console.log('TAG SENT', tagsSent);
                })
            );
        }
    }, [notifications]);
```

User Model:

```
    public function routeNotificationForOneSignal()
    {
    return ['tags' => ['key' => 'orders', 'relation' => '=', 'value' => 'orders']];
    }
```